# Bootstrap border issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I added `border-bottom: 5px solid #000;` on 45px div and then new div is 50px. That is Ok.

Then added `bootstrap.min.css (3.2.0)` and then div height total is 45px.

Is this an issue?

```
http://codepen.io/symbolicx/pen/ujwkJ (Div height 45+5 = 50px)

http://codepen.io/symbolicx/pen/JsqKH (Div height 45+5 = 45px)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there someone set a **border-box:** CSS property?

Comment: I dont know. Default bootsrap have it?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css `box-sizing:border-box` is already defined which gives `padding` from inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap adds the following Code as you can see if you inspect the `div` with e.g. Firebug

```
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You have to override *border-box* by your local CSS like:

```
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /*Note: content-box is the default if no box-sizing is set explicitly */
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
```

See the live example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJzxe).